# Generating a number based on a specified length of digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate the number x with based on a specified digit length of n. For example:

```
n = 3
x = n-digits length where each digit is the number n, thus 333.

n = 2
x = n-digits length where each digit is the number n, thus 22.
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this exclusively with numerical operations, without having to resort to string representations, and in closed form, without having to use any looping or recursion: `n*(10**n-1)//9`

Answer (score 4):

You can perform multiplication on string:

```
int(str(n) * n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this iteratively, like so:

```
def generatenumber(N):
    R=0
    for i in range(0, N): R+=N * 10**i
    return R
```